# Spring jdbcTemplate -add filter to query

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I write a queries in jdbcTemplate to create reports, Now I want to add filter to the reports. for example if i have query to create report of all contacts per day,  now I want to filter it that be just between two dates **not all** 
What  the best way to do it ?
There is a special way to do it in Spring jdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following [tutorial](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-jdbc-template-named-params/) and example code taken from that one below.

```
public Person select(String name){
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("name", name);

     String selectAllSql = "SELECT * FROM PERSON where name = :name";

     List<Person> persons = getJdbcTemplate().query(selectAllSql, new PersonRowMapper(),parameters);

     return persons.get(0);
  }

}
```

To answer your comment:

> If some times i dont use the filter what i do with the parmeters what i have to send

You have two options

1) You will need to use if statements to construct your sql and parameters.
2) Use another library for this purpose. I used [ElSql](https://github.com/OpenGamma/ElSql) in production before.

Comment: If some times i dont use the filter  what i do with the parmeters what i have to send?